# Understanding TCP memory management in Linux kernel

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

I'm Implementing a custom transport layer protocol on top of UDP to provide robust delivery services and need to ensure proper memory management. I'm trying to use TCP as a reference and see how the function `tcp_sendmsg()` handles memory constraints.

In the kernel code for `tcp_sendmsg()`,

```
if (!sk_stream_memory_free(sk))
    goto wait_for_sndbuf;

wait_for_sndbuf:
    set_bit(SOCK_NOSPACE, &sk->sk_socket->flags);
```

So the SOCK_NOSPACE flag is set for the socket. But how and where is the bit cleared later? And how does the `tcp_sendmsg()` function know that the bit has been cleared and it can resume sending the data?

**Edit 1**: As suggested by Maxim in his answer, the function `sk_stream_wait_memory()` handles the waiting for TCP. Can my protocol, which is built on top of UDP, use this "stream" function as well?

Answer (score 1):

> So the SOCK_NOSPACE flag is set for the socket. But how and where is the bit cleared later?

This bit is cleared when the data has been copied (or dropped) from the outgoing socket buffer into the outgoing queue of the device by the queueing discipline.

> And how does the tcp_sendmsg() function know that the bit has been cleared and it can resume sending the data?

There is [`while (msg_data_left(msg))`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L1152) loop with `sk_stream_wait_memory` call in it. `sk_stream_wait_memory` does the waiting.

Comment: Thank you Maxim. Can I use `sk_stream_wait_memory` for my protocol as well? My protocol runs on top of UDP and hence is not a "stream" protocol

Comment: @GauravSuman I would have to read the kernel code to answer that.